# Proper conjugation of verbs like flüstern, lächeln in the first person singular

Tags: verb, spelling, conjugation

What's the most common way to conjugate verbs for "Ich" when the infinitive ends with a consonant followed by n?

For lächeln mentioned above, Wiktionary gives Ich *lächle*, *lächele* and *lächel*. Does it vary by region, or is there a commonly accepted spelling?

Comment: In case of "lächeln" I usually "lächle" or "lächel". Very rarely "lächele". As of "flüstern", I never "flüstre", but "flüster" or "flüstere".

Answer (score 3):

In German verbs ending in *-eln* or *-ern*, you remove the final *n* to get the verb's *infinitive stem*, but you can then optionally drop the last *e* in the infinitive stem in the first person singular of the Indikativ Präsens/ present indicative.
For verbs ending in *-eln* (e.g. *blinzeln*, *jubeln*, *klingeln*, *pendeln*, *prügeln*, *pinseln*), you can also do this for all forms of the Konjunktiv I / present subjunctive.

*Lächeln* is conjugated in the same way as *handeln*.
*Flüstern* is conjugated in the same way as *wandern* (other examples: *hindern*, *lagern*, *plündern*).

The forms *ich lächele* and *ich lächle* are official.
I doubt that *ich lächel* is official: except for most modal and auxiliary verbs (*sein*, *sollen*, *dürfen*, ...), the first person singular of the present indicative ends in *-e*.